# Change the section color in europecv for "Personal information"

Tags: color, europecv

For changing the color of section titles I do this in `europecv`:

```
\newcommand{\mycvsection}[1]{\ecvsection{\textcolor{BrickRed}{#1}}}
```

This way the section title is red when I use:

```
\mycvsection{Section Title}
```

But when I use:

```
\ecvpersonalinfo
```

I can not use the macro. Can I somehow color the personal information section to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ecvpersonalinfo` doesn't use the regular `\ecvsection` to set another section. Instead you'll have to tap into the `Personal Information` section macro to change the colour.

The following minimal code does exactly that:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\let\old@ecv@infosectionkey\ecv@infosectionkey% Copy \ecv@infosectionkey
\renewcommand{\ecv@infosectionkey}
  {\textcolor{BrickRed}{\old@ecv@infosectionkey}}% Update colour to BrickRed
\makeatother
```

[image]

I used a [ShareLaTeX template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/europecv).